# Can we use Insertion sort on linked list without using any other data structure?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have gone through following link

http://analgorithmaday.blogspot.in/2011/01/insertion-sort-using-linked-list.html

They are using another array (*arr) to do the sorting.

Is it possible, to do the insertion sort, on the linked list without using any other array or linked list?

Comment: Yes. What problems are you having implementing it? (That article uses an array as a data source. Could be anything else, it's not really part of the sorting.)

Comment: Yes, buy my source of data is the List itself not some array.

Comment: You're trying to sort a list in-place, using insertion-sort? That's doesn't make much sense. Do the sorting at the same time you build your list in that case (i.e. your "insert" function or whatever should insert at the right place to start with). But yes, still possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your reading of their algorithm is not correct -- the passed-in array is simply the source of the data and is not used for the insertion sort.

Insertion sort is a good algorithm for small vectors and short linked lists too. A good method for linked lists can be to insertion sort small chunks (10 - 50 elements) and then recursively merge sort the linked lists until one sorted list remains.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion Sort is an in-place algorithm, which means that it does not need any auxiliary memory space to order an array or whatever.

If you use Insertion Sort on an array, you have to exchange the elements inside it while executing the algorithm, but if you have a linked list, you can exchange the pointers instead of the elements inside the list itself.